# Application to Publish custom messages on User's wall by Itself

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-wall

I developed simple Facebook app for my WordPress plugin (I used `PHP-SDK`) and it works like this:

1. A visitor clicks Facebook button on my website and his details (name and email) are saved to email autoresponder (`Aweber`, `iContact` or any other autoresponder) and my app publishes a post on user's Facebook wall.

But I want to make this app better and add an option, which will allow my plugin to publish on users' walls anytime. So once user clicks the button and allow me to post on his wall, then I can post on his wall anytime afterwards. It would be some `textarea` in my plugin for to write wall message and then I click 'publish' button and this message is posted on walls of all users, who used my Facebook button on my website. I hope it's not too confusing ;)

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: So you want users to give you the right to post status updates as if you were them at any time? I don't think your users will appreciate that - it sounds a bit *spammy*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid if this is possible anymore ..since facebook no longer allow offline_access ,so you may not be able to post on walls if a user is offline.to post on a wall when a user is online and have permitted u,u may use a database to store their access tokens and use that access token to publish on their wall.